# Downloading multiple images using Android Work Manager and Updating UI

Tags: android, multithreading, android-jetpack

I am stuck at a problem where I want to download multiple images from the web  (I have a list of URLs) using Work Manager. As I am downloading those files, I need to update a progressbar on the UI and also maintain a notification in status bar.

I have managed to update the notification but cannot get my head around communicating with the UI.

I have tried using EventBus and LocalBroadcasts, but they are old methods. I believe Work Manager would also have a solution for this.

If anyone has any clue, please let me know how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is useful, check this download manager in github [Download manager](https://github.com/tonyofrancis/Fetch)

Comment: Although this is really good, but the project I'm working on requires me to use Work Manager only :(

Comment: you already check this doc?

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics.html

Comment: I did. It gives back a result in the form of Live Data. But not for individual requests. It gives success or failure. I want a progressive callback.

Comment: @PrabhuV Don't you think your supposed to provided some solution  through code than pointing to some ready made library ?? How will people learn ?

Answer (score 0):

When using WorkManager you should use LiveData to update the UI. I highly recommend you take a look on the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52386924/update-ui-from-a-workmanager) I think it will significantly help you.